# apt-get & synaptic: what recently changed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, synaptic

I've rolled several Debian repositories for my projects (e.g. [erlang-dbus](http://code.google.com/p/erlang-dbus/)) and now on the Ubuntu 9.04 machines I have updated recently, my packages do not show up on Synaptics **but** I can still manage them through apt-get on a console.

How can I correct this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely that Synaptic started requiring (by default) that repositories must be signed.

Look for an option like that, and make sure `apt-get update` runs clean.

The version in Debian Testing (0.62.9) doesn't seem to have this issue.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  I've checked Synaptic's option to no avail: can't find knobs related to repository authentication.